# How to check if used Samsung Galaxy S23 has original bootloader, firmware, and software?

Tags: samsung, bootloader-lock, samsung-knox

I bought a used Samsung Galaxy S23 from a large online seller. How can I check that all the software and firmware is original and not tampered with?

I already did a factory reset from the settings menu. I'm wondering if there's a way to check the bootloader, firmware and other important systems.

I tried rebooting into Download-mode (phone off, hold both volume buttons and plug in USB power), and the Knox status says KG STATUS: CHECKING(00). It never updates away from "CHECKING".

Note that I don't have a SIM card yet. The phone was sold as originally Verizon locked but is now unlocked.

Comment: [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo.plus) was considered good...IDK currently how it performs

Answer (score 0):

Search for Safetynet checker on Google Play, download it then run the check. If the results were good then it's very likely that you have a stock/original system image from device manufacturer.